# In memory or actual stored database

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In Spring, I was switching over from MySQL to use MongoDB instead.

In MySQL, I can have an in-memory database (H2) and an actual locally stored database in MySQL. Is this not possible with MongoDB? If so, how? Is Spring Data MongoDB an in-memory one or locally stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's possible, try to check this embedded one: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo

example of usage: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb

Comment: Does 'embedded' mean in-memory or locally-stored?

Comment: This one is in-memory

Comment: So if you want locally-stored database instead of in-memory, do you use Spring Data MongoDB then?

Comment: Spring Data MongoDB - is a high-level abstraction for storing and querying documents, it's not the actual database.

Comment: My bad, in new versions of the lib (flapdoodle.embed.mongo) you can persist the state in file, such as in H2

https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo#custom-database-directory

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I used Fongo a few years ago:
https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo